# custom permutation python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Given this dictionary

```
dictt={2:'abc',3:'def',4:'gfi',5:'jkl',6:'mno',7:'pqrs',8:'tuv',9:'wxyz'}
```

i need to do a custom permutation.

the numbers in the input will tell you how long the output will be.

The input will also point at the letters being permutated.

for example. "34" will make the program return the first letter of the first sequence and add all 3 letters of the second sequence one by one.
a+d=ad a+e=ae a+d=af
then it will take the second letter of the first sequence and add all 3 letters of the second sequence
b+d=bd b+e=be b+f=bf
then third letter
c+d=cd c+e=ce c+f=cf
so when u enter 34 it will return ad ae af bd be bf cd ce cf
if the input was 3 numbers. then output would be pairs of 3. 
if the input was one number. then the output would be just the corresponding sequence listed. `ex: "2" would return a b c`

```
def permuteString(numString):
    array=[]
    original={2:'abc',3:'def',4:'gfi',5:'jkl',6:'mno',7:'pqrs',8:'tuv',9:'wxyz'}
    for a,b in original.iteritems():
        print a,b
        for c in b:
            print c

    return array

stuff=permuteString("234")
```

so far all i did was just pull the dictionary out

Comment: What's the "4" in "34 for then?

Comment: what's the `34` mean. in the dictt,`3:'abc'` ,`4:'def'`. If you input `34`, why not output `dg df di eg ef ei fg ff fi`? I don't know what do you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Written as a generator class:

```
import itertools

class PhoneWords(object):
    letters = {
        2: 'abc',
        3: 'def',
        4: 'ghi',
        5: 'jkl',
        6: 'mno',
        7: 'pqrs',
        8: 'tuv',
        9: 'wxyz'
    }

    def __init__(self, num_string):
        self.num = [int(i) for i in num_string]                 # => [3, 4]
        self.chars = [PhoneWords.letters[i] for i in self.num]  # -> ['def', 'ghi']

    def __iter__(self):
        return (''.join(letters) for letters in itertools.product(*self.chars))
```

and in use:

```
for word in PhoneWords("34"):
    print word
```

returns

```
dg
dh
di
eg
eh
ei
fg
fh
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is you want:

```
>>>from itertools import product
>>>def permuteString(numString):
>>>    original = {2:'abc',3:'def',4:'gfi',5:'jkl',6:'mno',7:'pqrs',8:'tuv',9:'wxyz'}
>>>    #extract the wanted string, for example input numString='23', the pools is ['abc', 'def']
>>>    pools = [original[int(n)] for n in numString]                                                 
>>>    return (''.join(x) for x in product(*pools)) #return a generator
```

And use by this way

```
>>>for x in permuteString('23'):
>>>    print x
ad
ae
af
bd
be
bf
cd
ce
cf
```

Detail:

**product** :[Cartesian product of input iterables](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

**generator**:[a simple and powerful tool for creating iterators](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators)

**join**: is can join the list, for example:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
print ''.join(x)
```

This would output:

```
'abcd'
```

Comment: can it be done without 'join' and 'pools'? and id rather have return as the final answer. and thank you so much, your so useful

Comment: @thebiggerchadder Because `product` return tuple generator. So we should use `join` to get `str` object.`pools` just a temporary variable

Comment: @shihongzhi: I think you could improve this answer by including a detailed explanation of what exactly is going on here.